# Subtracting count values in UNIX

Tags: unix

I am trying to subtracts one count value from another but,I am facing problem in following code :

count=$?

count1=$?

(then some operations and above count values got some value suppose 1,2 respectively)

$count=$count1 - $count     ==> Here it should get :  2-1=1 )

I don't know exact syntax for this so, can any one help me please?

Comment: You're talking about shell scripting, right?

Comment: Yes.. Barmar.. actually I am new to this So, cannt tell excactly... can you please clarify me please

Comment: If you don't know what you're asking about, it's hard for me to clarify for you. Are you writing a bash script, perl, PHP, whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shell's expression syntax:

```
count=$(($count1-$count))
```

the `$` prefix on variables is optional inside `$(())`, so this can also be written as:

```
count=$((count1-count))
```

Comment: Barmar : Thanks for ur answer... its working correctly now... :)

Answer (score 0):

Unix provides you the command `expr` that lets you evaluate any arithmetic expression you want. At shell prompt try :

```
expr 2 - 3 + 5 '*' 8
```

Remember that `*` is used as wildcard so you need to un-specialized it in any way you want.

Then now, you could use ` to evaluate an expression at any place :

```
count=`expr $count1 - $count`
```

Be aware that all arguments MUST be separated with spaces.

This will work for Bourne-shell which is the one recommended for shell-scripts.